# Cannot override final method Exception::__clone() imagick

Tags: php, imagick

```
<?php
    include_once 'imagick.php';

    $im = imagegrabscreen();
    imagepng($im, "myscreenshot.png");
    imagedestroy($im);

    $im = new Imagick('myscreenshot.png');
    $imageprops = $im->getImageGeometry();
    $width = $imageprops['width'];
    $height = $imageprops['height'];

    if($width > $height){
        $newHeight = 80;
        $newWidth = (80 / $height) * $width;
    }else{
        $newWidth = 80;
        $newHeight = (80 / $width) * $height;
    }

    $im->resizeImage($newWidth,$newHeight, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
    $im->cropImage (80,80,0,0);
    $im->writeImage( "test.jpg" );
    echo '<img src="test.jpg">';
?>
```

The image is being saved properly. However I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot override final method Exception::__clone() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: Show the imagick.php code please. And what php version? Its likely that file you are including is not meant for your php version.

Comment: @n099y i am unable to see the code within functions of imagick.php. I am sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: Can you do this :   print_r(Imagick::getVersion());

Comment: @n099y I guess than I am not including the imagick file correctly, as this line of code is not showing me anything

Comment: So that file, where is it, you should be able to open it up correct ? Normally no this is not how you use imagick, that is why i am asking to see whats inside that file.

Comment: it is some 6500 lines of code and i am unable to expand the functions to see the code within

Comment: I think you need to look into installing imagick on your server, you should not have to include it like you are doing, its normally installed.